# DBCC Inconsistency

Tags: sql-server, maintenance, dbcc-checkdb

I can run

```
DBCC CHECKDB ([vsc]) WITH NO_INFOMSGS, ALL_ERRORMSGS, DATA_PURITY
```

I get:

> Msg 8928, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
>   Object ID 1993058136, index ID 1, partition ID 72057594058964992, alloc unit ID 71906736119218176 (type LOB data): Page (1:364891) could not be processed.  See other errors for details.
>   Msg 8928, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
>   Object ID 1993058136, index ID 1, partition ID 72057594058964992, alloc unit ID 71906736119218176 (type LOB data): Page (1:364892) could not be processed.  See other errors for details.
>   Msg 8965, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
>   Table error: Object ID 1993058136, index ID 1, partition ID 72057594058964992, alloc unit ID 71906736119218176 (type LOB data). The off-row data node at page (1:364891), slot 0, text ID 8758125395968 is referenced by page (1:364893), slot 1, but was not seen in the scan.
>   Msg 8965, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
>   Table error: Object ID 1993058136, index ID 1, partition ID 72057594058964992, alloc unit ID 71906736119218176 (type LOB data). The off-row data node at page (1:364892), slot 0, text ID 8758125395968 is referenced by page (1:364893), slot 1, but was not seen in the scan.
>   Msg 8929, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
>   Object ID 1993058136, index ID 1, partition ID 72057594058964992, alloc unit ID 72057594063355904 (type In-row data): Errors found in off-row data with ID 8758125395968 owned by data record identified by RID = (1:2218280:70)
>   CHECKDB found 0 allocation errors and 5 consistency errors in table 'wm_scanimages' (object ID 1993058136).
>   CHECKDB found 0 allocation errors and 5 consistency errors in database 'vsc'.

But then I run the same command and it comes back with no errors, I have read about transient IO errors, but how can I pin them down?

Comment: Try running `DBCC CHECKDB ([vsc]) WITH TABLOCK, NO_INFOMSGS, ALL_ERRORMSGS, DATA_PURITY` .. notice the `tablock` hint. What version and service pack/CU of sql server are you using ?

Comment: Try using the WITH TABLOCK option to force a table lock.  LOB data restricts the types of ONLINE operations you can perform on the object.  DBCC CHECKDB uses database snapshots, making it an ONLINE operation. The WITH TABLOCK options forces a table lock making it an OFFLINE operation.  The downside, of course, is you will not be able to access that table until DBCC CHECKDB completes.  Follow the link for more info - https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2399/minimize-performance-impact-of-sql-server-dbcc-checkdb/